# Aunque + condicional

Tags: preposiciones, sintaxis, condicional

Pensaba que las subordinadas concesivas se construyen con subjuntivo (bueno a veces también con indicativo). Aquí tengo un ejemplo:

> **Aunque** le habría gustado señalarle que nadie estaba en aquel almuerzo
>   por lo que pensaba sino por los méritos de su alcurnia.

¿Es normal que *aunque* vaya en condicional?

Comment: Creo que son mejores ejemplos _aunque le haya gustado_ y _aunque le hubiera gustado_. "Habría" es el condicional. (Aunque alguien en este sitio alguna vez me explicó que los condicionales pertenecen al subjuntivo. Creo que fue guifa).

Answer (score 2):

Sí, es perfectamente idiomático, indica que la acción no ocurrió.

> **Aunque** le habría gustado señalarle = Pero no se lo señaló.

Es parte de la clásula de esta especie de condicional, por ejemplo:

> **Aunque** le habría gustado señalarle <s>***si hubiese/hubiera tenido la oportunidad***</s> que nadie estaba en aquel almuerzo por lo que pensaba si no por los méritos de su alcurnia.